# Return typescript union with wasm_bindgen

Tags: typescript, rust, union-types, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm

Suppose I have the following rust structs:

```rust
struct NumberNode { 
    val: i64
}
struct StringNode {
    val: String
}

pub enum Node {
    Number(NumberNode),
    String(StringNode),
}
```

I would like to annotate `Node` with `#[wasm_bindgen]` so I can return it from wasm to javascript.

This somewhat describes the structure I would like to recceive in javascript.

```js
enum NodeType { Number, String };

interface NumberNode { typ: NodeType.Number, val: number };
interface StringNode { typ: NodeType.String, val: string };

type Node = NumberNode | StringNode;
```

Comment: union type `Node` seems to be correct

Comment: @captain-yossarian That is typescript code I wrote. I want to know how to get wasm_bindgen to generate (something similar to) this.

Comment: It's not even about the typescript output I care that much, but rather how I would even go about returning such a struct from wasm.

Comment: But you already have rust `enum Node`. Rust does not have `|` operator and you can't do a union of types in a way you do it in typescript. `pub enum Node` seems to be a closest representation of typescript union type `Node`. Please be aware that Rust have `union` concept https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/unions.html but it is not even similar to typescript union

Comment: could you please share a github repo or minimum reproducable example? I will try to help

Comment: @captain-yossarian I know that they are not the same. But how would I go about converting it into that? I have multiple nodes with different content, and I want to return them to JS. I've updated my question somewhat, hope it better describe it.

Comment: @Elias I expect you either can or have to use `serde` to get data out of `wasm-bindgen` (that's probably noted in the wasm-bindgen book or whatever), in which case [you can configure the `enum`'s external representation](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html). The typescript you wrote up is an "internally tagged" enum.

Comment: @Masklinn So it's not possible to do something like this https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/issues/111#issuecomment-527380864?

Comment: Because I basically want to return `Vec<Node>`

Comment: @Masklinn I hoped I could achieve something like described here https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/2407/886065802

Comment: It seems to me like that's very much possible, through serde, either using the built-in support of wasm-bindgen or using serde-wasm-bindgen. As I suspected [there's a page on that subject in the guide](https://github.com/rustwasm/wasm-bindgen/blob/44d577f6b89dc7cc572ea0747833d38ba680e93b/guide/src/reference/arbitrary-data-with-serde.md). If you don't want to use serde for some reason (???) then you get to do the conversion by hand.

Comment: @Masklinn Well I'm writing a json parser, I was hoping not relying on another json parser to pass the parsed data back to js.

Comment: @Masklinn how much work would the conversion by hand be? And is there any documentation on it? The thing is that I'm very new to rust, I basically only started writing it to generate wasm.

Comment: You'd have to create a layout wasm-bindgen can handle natively out of the box, so you'll probably have to go through the guide to know. At this point it's way beyond my ken I fear.

Comment: And writing a json parser in a wasm context seems something of an odd idea I've got to say, the main use case I'd see would be a non-validating streaming parser (as javascript doesn't provide one out of the box) but I'd expect the back and forth through wasm to be costly.

Comment: @Masklinn Okay thank you for your time :) As to why I am doing this, writing a parser is really good practice and teaches you a lot about coding (and the deeper concepts of it). Even though I haven't implemented anything like variables yet, I now have some understanding (after writing the tree builder of my json parser), how I would write scope specific dictionaries and so on to implement varaibles in json. :)